# Outputting array from binary file to program

Tags: java, arrays, binary

I am needing to output an array i sent to a binary file back out to my program. Here is the code that i have so far...

```
Animal[] zoo =new Animal[9]; 
zoo[0]= new Hawk ("red tailed", 5); 
zoo[1]= new Hawk ("red tailed", 5); 
zoo[2]= new Hawk ("white tailed", 4); 

zoo[3]= new Elephant ("african elephant", 4);
zoo[4]= new Elephant ("african elephant", 4);
zoo[5]= new Elephant ("canadian elephant", 4);

zoo[6]= new Snake ("white tailed", 4);
zoo[7]= new Snake ("white tailed", 4);
zoo[8]= new Snake ("white tailed", 4);

Hawk h1=new Hawk("red hawk",5);

String fileName="out.bin";
try{
  FileOutputStream fileOs =new FileOutputStream(fileName);
  DataOutputStream os= new DataOutputStream(fileOs);
  os.writeUTF(h1.getname());
  os.writeInt(h1.getwing());
  os.close();
  System.out.println("Hawk info sent to binary file");
} catch (FileNotFoundException e){
  e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e){
  e.printStackTrace();
}

try{
  FileInputStream fileOs =new FileInputStream(fileName);
  DataInputStream os= new DataInputStream(fileOs);
  System.out.println("Hawk info read from binary file: "+ os.readUTF()+"  "+ os.readInt());
  os.close();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e){
  e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e){
  e.printStackTrace();
}  

String fileName1=("out.bin1");
try{
   FileOutputStream fileOs =new FileOutputStream(fileName1);
  ObjectOutputStream os= new ObjectOutputStream(fileOs);
  os.writeObject(zoo);
  //os.writeInt(h1.getwing());
  os.close();
  System.out.println("Animal array info sent to binary file");
} catch (FileNotFoundException e){
  e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e){
  e.printStackTrace();
}

try{
  FileInputStream fileOs =new FileInputStream(fileName1);
  ObjectInputStream os= new ObjectInputStream(fileOs);
  //os.readObject((Animal)zoo); 
  System.out.println("Successfully transfered array data from binary file");
  os.close();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e){
  e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e){
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

}
}

Soo basically i had no compiler error etc sending the code to the binary file, but i am just unsure on how to get it back... if someone could show me that would be very appreciated.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

The readObject method (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html#readObject()) is what you want, you just need to cast the RESULT to the class you expect:

```
zoo=(Animal[])os.readObject();
```

It may throw other exceptions like ClassNotFoundException.